# Alternative for filtering out only first element of a list that matches some element

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to think of an alternative to the List method for `remove(int index)`  and `remove(T element)`. Where I take a list and do some filtering and return a new list without the element requested to be removed. I want to do it functionally, as I don't want to mutate the original list.

Here is my attempt.

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1);
Integer elementToRemove = 1;
List<Integer> collect = 
           integers.stream()
                   .filter(elements -> !elements.equals(elementToRemove))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will remove all the 1's.

I wont to remove just the first `1`, so I will be left with a list like `[2,4,2,5,1]`

I know how to do it using `indexOf()` and `sublist()` and `addAll()`. But I feel this is not as good as using streams.

Looking for functional solutions using streams for implementing `remove(int index)`  and `remove(T element)`.

Comment: Why do you think streams are better for this case? I don't think they are.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to do it functionally, as I dont want to mutate the original
>   list.

You can still perform the removal operation and not mutate the source without going functional.

> But I feel this is not as good as using streams.

Quite the opposite as this is done better without streams:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(integers); // copy the integers list
result.remove(Integer.valueOf(elementToRemove)); // remove from the new list leaving the old list unmodified
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Aominè but this can be a alternative in stream API

```
IntStream.range(0,integers.size())
           .filter(i->i != integers.indexOf(elementToRemove)) 
           .mapToObj(i->integers.get(i))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As @Aominè commented for optimize, find index of `elementToRemove` firstly then use it in the filter.

Comment: use `IntStream.range(0, integers.size())` instead of `IntStream.rangeClosed(0,integers.size()-1)`

Comment: you can optimise this further by storing the result of `indexOf` prior to the stream pipeline, meaning you don't have to search for the element index on each element pass. i.e. `int elementIndex = integers.indexOf(elementToRemove); IntStream.range(0, integers.size()).filter(i -> i != elementIndex).....`. +1

Answer (score 1):

While my other answer is definitely the way I recommend to proceed with and @Hadi has also provided the "stream" alternative which is also valid. I decided to play about with different ways to achieve the same result using features as of JDK-8.

In JDK-9 there is a [takeWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [dropWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) methods where the former returns a stream consisting of the longest prefix of elements taken from a stream that match a given predicate.

The latter returns a stream consisting of the remaining elements of a given stream after dropping the longest prefix of elements that match a given predicate.

The idea here is to consume the elements while it's not equal to the `elementToRemove`:

```
integers.stream()
        .takeWhile(e -> !Objects.equals(e, elementToRemove))
```

and drop the elements while it's not equal to the `elementToRemove` and `skip(1)` to exclude the `elementToRemove`:

```
integers.stream()
        .dropWhile(e -> !Objects.equals(e, elementToRemove))
        .skip(1)
```

hence yielding two streams where the first stream is all the preceding numbers to `elementToRemove` and the second stream plus the `skip(1)` is all the elements after the `elementToRemove` then we simply concatenate them and collect to a list implementation.

```
List<Integer> result = Stream.concat(integers.stream()
                        .takeWhile(e -> !Objects.equals(e, elementToRemove)),
                integers.stream()
                        .dropWhile(e -> !Objects.equals(e, elementToRemove))
                        .skip(1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming the element to remove does not exist in the list the `takeWhile` will consume all the elements and the `dropWhile` will drop all the elements and when we merge these two streams we get back the initial elements.

Overall this will accomplish the same result as the other answers.

*However, **do not use this solution in production code** as it's suboptimal and not obvious to the eye what the code does. it's only here to show different ways to accomplish the said requirement.*